# Will a remastered debian for powerpc still be in the powerpc architecture?

Tags: debian, powerpc

I would like to know because I am going to use a power pc mac g5 for making my distribution. I also need to know if it makes my remaster the powerpc architecture and how to change it to 32 or 64-bit if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, if you're creating your own distribution based on Debian, the `powerpc` architecture can be whatever you want it to be; in Debian it's "only" a name in [`dpkg`'s tables](https://git.dpkg.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/data/cputable).

If you do change your definition of an architecture though, you'd be better off changing the architecture name; for a good example of what happens when you don't, see Raspbian (where `armhf` isn't the same as Debian's `armhf`).

`powerpc` in Debian is 32-bit; there's a 64-bit port, [`ppc64`](https://wiki.debian.org/PPC64) (and a 64-bit little-endian port, [`ppc64el`](https://wiki.debian.org/ppc64el), but that's not relevant for a G5). If you want to mix both you'd use [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) typically.

So the answer to your question depends on what changes you intend to make in your "remastering"...

Comment: So how do I use Multiarch? Is that the best method?

Comment: You'll need to explain what you're trying to do in more detail if you want to know what the best method is...

Comment: I want to make a distro based on debian on a Powerpc and intend to redistribute it with linux live kit but I also want it to be compatible with other computers.

Comment: You want a single live system which can work on multiple architectures?

Comment: I actually think that would work better than having one or more archetectures  so yes.

Comment: You realise that's not possible in the general case? You can use `i386` on a 32- or 64-bit *x86* PC, `powerpc` on a 32- or 64-bit PowerPC, but a `powerpc` live system won't work on a *x86* PC... Even if you wanted to mix architectures using multiarch, it wouldn't work: multiarch supports co-installable libraries, not co-installable binaries.

Comment: So I can't use a Powerpc to make my distro?

Comment: Will using a i386 for the archetecture work insteard? I know that is 32-bit willb I n stalling debian 32-bit work? I don't know what to do then

Comment: So if I can't use Multiarch what do I do?

Comment: I can't, all I have is my phone at the moment and the site won't let me log in for some reason... I will try looking into this further